# Visual Studio Extension that can Modify Variable Names

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I'm trying to build a **Visual Studio**(not VSCode) extension that can be started from the tools menu and  can write over variable names in code. However, while looking around extending the editor documentation(classifier, adornments etc.), I didn't find what I'm looking for.

What I do know:

1. I figured out how to add command to the tools menu
2. I can print out a status message for debugging whatever I'm doing

What I don't know:

1. Getting access to the file currently being edited in Visual Studio
2. Getting access to the code inside of it
3. If there are methods available to differentiate local variable names, method names, etc...

How would I go about this?

Comment: Please add a tag about `visual-studio-extentions` .

Comment: I have added it.